# Linux Open default terminal text editor

Tags: linux, bash

How do you open a plain text file in the user's default text editor for terminal in a bash script? 
xdg-open will open the file in the default gui editor, is there an equivalent for terminal editors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the system is properly configured,  `editor` should do the job.

For instance, on my debian system, editor is configured to use nano.

```
$ update-alternatives --display editor
editor - auto mode
  link currently points to /bin/nano
/bin/nano - priority 40
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
/usr/bin/emacs23 - priority 0
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/emacs.emacs23.1.gz
/usr/bin/vim.basic - priority 30
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.fr.1.gz: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.it.1.gz: /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.pl.1.gz: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ru.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/bin/vim.tiny - priority 10
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.fr.1.gz: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.it.1.gz: /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.pl.1.gz: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ru.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/bin/nano'.
```

I was expecting it to use the environnement variable EDITOR, but obviously it's not the case, at least on Debian.

Comment: What is properly configured? I tried `editor` but it opens nano when I have `export EDITOR=vim` in my bashrc and programs like crontab use vim. @tripleee Using `$EDITOR [filename]` seems to work.

Comment: I tried it out on a fresh VM and Using `$EDITOR [filename]` works only if you have the `EDITOR` variable configured. I found out the proper way to setup the defualt editor as `sudo update-alternatives –config editor` and your solution works!

Comment: `alias emacs="vim" && alias nano="vim" && alias whatever="vim"` :-D

Comment: You might need to use `VISUAL` instead of `EDITOR`.